# How can background processes interact with users in PC/Mac environments?

Tags: notifications, background, tray

Currently we are using System Tray/Notification Tray to interact with users from a background process. I wanted to know if there are more modern and recommended ways to do the same.

Something that would apply to both Windows and Mac?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I read about is exposing an API and use a web UI frontend to interact with the API. That I guess would be similar to have an HTTP endpoint on a web server.